# Synchronize iCloud with three computers using outlook

Tags: icloud, ms-office

is it possible to synchronize calendar and contacts via iCloud with three different computers? They're all using Outlook.

Comment: What do you want to synchronize? E-Mails? Calendar? Settings? Computer settings and files? Are you using POP3 or IMAP for E-Mail? Outlook is not using iCloud so far.

Comment: Are the three computers all Macs running Lion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Outlook you need to enable the OSX Addressbook and Calendar sync functions. It's call Sync Services under Preferences.

Basically, you'll use iCloud to sync your OSX Addressbook and Calendar across all three computers - that's a normal iCloud function. Then you'll use Outlooks Sync Services on each computer to sync into Outlook.

For calendars in iCloud you might be able to get then shared directly into Outlook, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If using Windows, you must set up each computer according to the instructions at http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html